# Is it ever a Chillul Hashem to discuss Torah principles?

Tags: gentiles, rambam, kiruv-outreach, chilul-kidush-hashem

The Rambam explains one type of Chillul Hashem as follows ([מיי' הל' יסודי התורה פ"ה הי"ד](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1105.htm)):

> ויש דברים אחרים שהם בכלל חילול השם, והוא שיעשה אדם גדול בתורה ומפורסם בחסידות, דברים שהברייות מרננים אחריו בשבילן, ואף על פי שאינם עבירות--הרי זה מחלל את השם:  כגון שלוקח ואינו נותן דמי הלקח לאלתר, והוא שיש לו, ונמצאו המוכרין תובעין אותו, והוא מקיפן; או שירבה בשחוק, או באכילה ושתייה אצל עמי הארץ וביניהן; או שאין דיבורו בנחת עם הברייות, ואינו מקבילן בסבר פנים יפות, אלא בעל קטטה וכעס; וכיוצא בדברים האלו.  הכול לפי גודלו של חכם--צריך שידקדק על עצמו, ויעשה לפנים משורת הדין.
>
> There are some other things included in Chillul Hashem [besides those involving overtly breaking mitzvos]. This is when a person who is learned in Torah and famous for his piety performs actions that cause others to denigrate him; despite the fact that they are not technically *aveiros*, this is Chillul Hashem. For example, if a person buys an item and does not pay immediately despite the fact that he has money on him, and the seller demands it from him and he takes the item on credit. Or, if he is excessively merry, or eats or drinks excessively among simpletons. Or, if he does not speak gently to others, and does not receive them kindly, but is often angry and argumentative. All of these sort of things are Chillul Hashem. A wise man must be scrupulous in his behavior and go beyond the letter of the law, according to his greatness.

When I was in yeshiva an incident occured where a student in the IDF refused to attend a military concert where women were singing and lost his position. Our shiur was discussing the halacha of the situation afterwards, and our Rebbe vehemtly disagreed with the suggestion that the student's action might have been a Chillul Hashem. This Rebbe said that when one is doing a mitzvah, it is not considered a Chillul Hashem if other people are offended by that mitzvah itself. What I took from this was that the Rambam means that in regards to *non-mitzvah-related actions*, one must act in a way that will not garner disapproval from others, but if one is doing an *actual mitzvah*, then if others disapprove it is their own fault that they don't appreciate the mitzvah, and therefore it is not considered Chillul Hashem. I don't know exactly what our Rebbe's source for this was, but I think the Chinuch agrees with him (see [מצווה תכא: להניח תפלין על היד](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34302&st=&pgnum=277) from "והמחמירים בקדושת המצוה" on, where he brings an opinion that it is a Chillul Hashem to wear tefillin when one's actions are not befitting, and argues on it).

Now here is my question: I was wondering whether this applies in the case where one is discussing or explaining Torah principles. There are certain halachos and hashkafic principles that are not "politically correct," and kiruv Rabbis and other Orthodox Jews who regularly interact with non-Orthodox Jews often avoid talking about them or whitewash them. (Examples: the issur to teach gentiles Torah, the laws of apikorsus, many gemaras discussing women, etc.) Now I understand that *pragmatically* it may be a bad idea to tell the non-Orthodox and gentiles about these details, since it might make it less likely that they will reach a higher level of avodas Hashem<sup>1</sup>. The question, though, is whether it is a *Chillul Hashem* to tell them about these things. Perhaps it is similar to the case of the incident I mentioned above, but this case is a little different since one is not actually *performing* a mitzvah. Would the Rambam say that one must "speak gently" and not reveal these things –slash– frame them in an overly positive way, or would he say that in the case of talking about Torah principles this law doesn't apply?

<sup>1</sup>(For example, the Rambam says on Avos 2:14 that דע מה להשיב לאפיקורס doesn't apply if the heretic is a Jew, since he may become more entrenched in his ways if you try to argue with him.)

Comment: "Slash"? Oh my. I hope that doesn't hurt.

Comment: On the substance, can you cite anyone saying anything similar? For example, do you know of anyone who says that we shouldn't discuss miracles with non-believers because they might ridicule the Torah? (+1, though.)

Comment: @SethJ I added the Rambam's comment on דע מה להשיב לאפיקורס. Let me know if you were thinking of some other source in particular.

Comment: This question would be stronger if you could cite an established text who took the opinion of your Rebbe.

Comment: After a cursory investigation I found a Chinuch that I think agrees with him -- I've added it to the answer.

Comment: For a posible source for your Rebbe's opinion, see also _Mesilat Yesharim_ [Ch. 20](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/mesilat/mesilat20-2.htm) (_be-Mishqal ha-Chasidut_), especially starting s.v. "הנה חייב האדם לשמור"( near the end of the chapter).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. And that Mesilas Yesharim also mentions that one should refrain from pious acts which will cause others to denigrate him and thereby sin; that might be directly applicable to this case.

Comment: It is true that you can't do a Chilul Hashem while doing a mitzvah.  However, that assume that what one is doing is actually a mitzvah. (In the case of that soldier, he wasn't actually doing a mitzvah, he could have gone and put in ear plugs)

Comment: @avi It's the not listening to kol isha that's the mitzvah. *How* to perform that mitzvah is a separate issue.

Comment: @Malper If I prevent myself from listening to kol isha, by killing the woman who's voice I might be hearing, that is certainly a Chilul hashem, and not doing a mitzvah. You can't argue that I'm doing a mitzvah, but you dissagree with the "how" (at least you shouldn't...)

Comment: @avi That's Chillul Hashem because you are doing an actual aveirah (retzichah). That's different. The Rambam I brought is talking specifically about Chillul Hashem that *does not involve an actual aveirah*.

Comment: @Malper embarrassing someone is also an eveirah. That's why I said, it depends if what you are doing is actually a mitzvah or not.

Comment: @avi I don't think the issue was embarrassing someone (I don't think the performers on stage even noticed the soldier exiting). The issue was the other audience members thinking that religious Jews are unrefined.

Answer (score 2):

We have laws that some things can not be taught to certain people. Teaching those people laws that you are not allowed to teach, especially if doing so makes Gd look bad, is certainly a Chilul Hashem.

Because of the public nature of this forum, I do not want to list what things you are not allowed to teach to which people.  But as you brought up in your question, "the issur to teach gentiles Torah". Another commonly known one is that you can not teach Ma'eseh Bereshit in front of more then one or two students.

You mentioned in your question:

> Perhaps it is similar to the case of the incident I
>   mentioned above, but this case is a little different since one is not
>   actually *performing* a mitzvah.

Incorrect, teaching Torah is a Mitzvah. When one is allowed to teach Torah. Talmud Torah is mainly about teaching.  See here:  [Rambam on the Mitzvah of Talmud Torah](http://www.torah.org/learning/rambam/talmudtorah/tt1.1.html)

> Would the Rambam say that one must
>   "speak gently" and not reveal these things / frame them in an
>   overly positive way, or would he say that in the case of talking about
>   Torah principles this law doesn't apply?

As you stated in your question, the only time this does not apply is when one is doing a mitzvah.  Since in the situations you mentioned, you are most likely not doing a mitzvah, and are likely in fact teaching someone who you are not supposed to teach (though not technically violating any of the negative commandments), then doing so is obviously a Chilul Hashem.

This is made explicitly clear by the Rambam in your question:

> This is when a person who is learned in Torah and famous for his
>   piety performs actions that cause others to denigrate him; despite the
>   fact that they are not technically aveiros, this is Chillul Hashem.

If what you are doing is not technically an aveirah, and what you are doing is not technically a mitzvah, then everything that Rambam says about Chillul Hashem applies.

Comment: That's not obvious to me at all. What is your source?

Comment: The Rambam in the question. It's simple logic. The Rambam in the question defines what Chilul Hashem is. I'm simplyfing that as "makes Gd look bad."
Teaching people who are not allowed to be taught, is a violation of halacha or atleast common sense, and thus falls under Rambam's definition.

Comment: How do you know that that's the reason for the issur of teaching gentiles Torah? I heard a different reason.

Comment: @Malper it's not the reason...  But since teaching that piece of Torah, is a violation of something, then you can't say you are doing a mitzvah, and thus all the rules of chilul hashem apply.

Comment: But my whole question is *whether* chillul Hashem applies when you're not doing a mitzvah. That just [begs the question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question).

Comment: No, you asked if chillul Hashem applies when discussing Torah concepts.  The Rambam you quoted is discussing chillul Hashem when not doing a mitzvah, but also not doing an aveirah.

Comment: How do you know that discussing Torah concepts is always a mitzvah?

Comment: @Malper it's not.. sometimes it's an aveirah...  But that seems to be the assumption of your question.

Comment: On the contrary -- my question only makes sense if it is *not* a mitzvah. Read it again carefully.

Comment: @Malper You have got to be kidding me...  I'll edit my answer to make this more clear...

Comment: Thanks for the edits -- the answer is much more coherent now.

Answer (score 0):

> I mentioned above, but this case is a little different since one is
>   not actually performing a mitzvah.

I would like to clarify the difference if I may. The boy who refused to listen to a woman sing is refraining from a sin. Chillul Hashem is an aveirah when one has a choice, on the other hand when one is commanded by g-d not to do something there is no aveirah of chillul hashem whether or not it causes someone to think bad things about g-d or his torah. G-d knows that not everyone will understand his mitzvos and he commanded them anyways. On the other hand to discuss the laws of the torah that are hard to understand with someone who is skeptical and will ridicule them is not something we are commanded to do so we do not have the above logic. Also we must keep in mind that much of the time we do not understand g-ds laws well enough to clearly explain it to someone who is skeptical so the chances of teaching it incorrectly are great enough that it may result in a chillul hashem by teaching it incorrectly. Meaning that to do this needs a very strong purpose and a very knowledgeable person.