# Does Lo Techanem apply to online Q&A sites?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, stackexchange

Regarding the issur of Lo Techanem, does this apply to giving answers to online Q&A sites such as Stack Overflow, where most likely the questioner is not Jewish?

Comment: Could you clarify why you think this would be an issue?

Comment: Gemara in Avodah Zarah (20a) derives from this verse that there is a prohibition to give gifts/ give favor... except for cases of darkei shalom

Comment: Why would answering a question be like giving a gift?

Comment: @ray Shouldn't that information be in the post not a comment?

Comment: @DoubleAA trying to keep it as quiet as possible for darkei shalom purposes.

Comment: @ray well i just saw it on twitter...

Comment: The issur is Lo tenacheM (from the word chinaM free)

Comment: @Ray, I understand what you're trying to do (I think) but I think a well-supported question that explains what you think the concerns are (or otherwise why you're asking) would be an improvement for this site.  Also remember that we have people at quite a range of knowledge levels here; not everybody will understand this question as written.

Comment: @ray See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33866/is-it-ever-a-chillul-hashem-to-discuss-torah-principles/33888

Comment: @ray ?? Darkei shalom? Do you mean mishum eivah? How is this darkei shalom?

Comment: @MonicaCellio i deliberately wrote it like this so only those who have a certain level of torah learning would understand the question - for darkei shalom. doubleaa u're right. trying to keep it vague.

Comment: @eramm FTR it's תחנם with a kamatz katan under the ח.

Comment: FWIW, I was taught that darchei shalom and eiva are two sides of the same coin.

Comment: @AdamMosheh I don't know what that means, but there's no question that they aren't the same thing.

Comment: @DoubleAA – I admit that they are not identical, but they are very similar. I can't exactly word what I'm trying to say, but eiva is negative and DS is positive.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Their results may be similar but their motivations are polar opposites. Eivah we just do to avoid damage. DS we actually want to do.

Comment: *Two sides of the same coin* is just an idiom. Who hasn't heard of it?

Comment: @AdamMosheh I've heard of the idiom. That doesn't mean that your using it allowed you to convey a precise message with your words.

Answer (score 4):

Tosfos understand that "Darchei Shalom" is not considered a gift. IMHO that means since you benefit from the resulting peace then it's not a free gift since its win-win for both sides. Similarly when you contribute to an online community you benefit that when *you* need assistance the online community will be available to help you. So it seems that since it's win-win it's not considered a "free gift".

The Rambam seems to understand that the issur was enacted so a person won't learn from gentiles' ways and get close to them. So again IMHO since online public community forums which are focused on work related topics seem *not* to foster a personal relationships with those you interact with it would be ok.

My Source:
http://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%9C%D7%90-%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%9D

Comment: "the issur was enacted" Are you claiming Lo Techonneim is a rabbinic prohibition?

Comment: @DoubleAA Didn't God enact _isurim_? Some 365 of them?

Comment: @msh210 I don't know that all traditional Jewish theologians would necessarily agree to that. (Though this is just for fun; my point above stands.)

Comment: @DoubleAA "The Rambam seems to understand that the issur was enacted..."

Comment: @msh210 Hence my questioning not asserting.

Comment: Sorry poor choice of words perhaps. On some days I can't tap my inner Artscroll :)